# how to prevent usage of class members not yet constructed?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have the following classes:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() { x = 0; std::cout<<"A default ctor()\n"; }
    A(int x_) { x = x_; std::cout<<"A normal ctor()\n"; }
    int x;
};

class B
{
public:
    B() { std::cout<<"B ctor()\n"; }
private:
std::string str;
};
```

and a function which creates an object B, taking an object A as parameter:

```
B
createB(const A& a) {
    std::cout<<"a int: "<<a.x<<"\n";
    return B();
}
```

if I design a class C, which has members of type A and B and constructs the B-object before A-object is constructed **but using the A object to do so**, this will compile without warnings but it will silently enter a bug:

```
class C
{
public:
    C(): b(createB(a)), a(10) {}
private:
    B b;
    A a;
};


int main()
{
    C c;
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, the above example is a trivial one, but I've seen it in real world, in much more complex code (it's Friday, 8:30 PM and I just fixed this bug which led to segfaults).

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Why don't you switch the order of the `B` and `A` in `C` so that the `A` is constructed first?

Comment: @SethCarnegie that will work, but it doesn't preclude the issue from cropping up again and again.  Better to rethink how these values are initialized, I think.

Comment: This is like "how do I keep myself from using uninitialised variables?" You just... _don't use uninitialised variables_. You have to remember to make everything be initialised when it needs to be.

Comment: Some compilers have warnings about using `this` or subobjects of `this` in mem-initializers, if you turn up the warning level really high.  But that will often cause lots of false positives too.  I agree with Seth, it pretty much comes down to "be careful".

Comment: Which concrete error led to the segfault, if `B` can't be constructed with a default constructed `A`? I think what you'll need is to assure that you have only valid references to `A` before calling `createB()` or omit that method at all, but replace with a constructor for `B` that takes a `const A&`. Then the compiler will at least warn you about the initialization order.

Comment: @g-makulik: There is no default constructed `A` object anywhere in the sample program.  Instead, it uses an object which has not yet been constructed at all.

Comment: @aschepler Thank's, I've noticed that also now, it's just not initialized at this point.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with what others have suggested, namely that the onus is on the designer to ensure that objects are initialized before use.  I see two ways of doing that in your case:

First (and easiest), reverse the order of `a` and `b` in the class definition:

```
class C
{
public:
    C(): b(createB(a)), a(10) {}
private:
    A a;
    B b;
};
```

Second, you could move `a` to a base class if you want to **really** emphasize that it's initialization occurs before that of other members:

```
class CBase
{
protected:
    CBase(): a(10) {}
protected:
    A a;
};

class C : private CBase
{
public:
    C(): b(createB(a)) {}
private:
    B b;
};
```

Comment: If you're only able to modify `C` your proposal using a base class would be the best choice, otherwise I would rethink the design with 'A', 'B' and `createB(const A& a)`completely.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, this seems like the best and simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I see three possible alternatives:

## Require `A` to be constructed prior to constructing `C`:

```
class C
{
public:
   C(const A& a) : a_(a), b_(a) {}
private:
   A a_;
   B b_;
};
```

## Construct `A` prior to constructing 'B':

Delaying the construction of `B` until `A` is complete.  This stops the undefined behavior from happening, but doesn't enforce proper behavior via the interface (as options 1 and 3 *do*)

```
class C
{
public:
   C() : a_(/* construct as appropriate */)
   {
      b_.reset(new B(a_));
   }

private:
   A a_;
   std::unique_ptr<B> b_;
};
```

## If the design allows for it, have `B` contain (and expose) `A`.

This appears possible from the trivial example, but in real life may not be:

```
class B
{
public:
   const A& my_a() {return a_;}
private:
   // construct as appropriate (?)
   A a_;
};

class C
{
private:
   B b_;
};
```

Comment: What is the point of the second one? If you put them in the wrong order you can still cause UB, just like the first one.

Comment: The `std::unique_ptr`?  We're not creating `B` until we're actually _in_ `C::C()`, after the initializer list has completed.  There is no way for the wrong order to happen.

Comment: I don't see the purpose of the second one, other than working as a shiny example of overengineering.

Comment: Apparently so you can delay the construction of the `B`, but that's pointless because you can just do the first one, _and_ the second one doesn't _require_ you to do anything, you can still initialise it in the initialiser list and cause UB.

Comment: Really?  You're both on the same page on this?  The second one seems like the easiest solution to the problem to me.  (We're talking about storing a pointer to `B` that is constructed after we know `A` is complete.

Comment: The first one is my preferred way to handle this (hence why it is listed first), but the second one doesn't seem _offensive_ (to me at least)  :)

Comment: Awww crap.  Cut and past error.  See if that clarifies it now.  The second one was meant to default construct `A` to minimize the interface changes to `C` which can be a big factor in a large codebase.

Comment: @Chad it's not offensive, just unnecessary. And my main point was it doesn't make you do anything. Some other programmer could say "hey, you should initialise member variables in the initialiser list not in the constructor, let me move that up there" and break it because it doesn't make you do anything. The headline says **Require A to be constructed prior to constructing 'B'** But it doesn't require that at all.

Comment: @SethCarnegie - You're absolutely right, the way it was coded before my last edit option 2 was just bad.  I've edited it now to more closely reflect the OP's interface. However, if we explicitly have pointers (or smart pointers) in a class to delay construction, that is a pretty common technique.

Comment: Actually that doesn't really make it better in any way that I can see.

Comment: May be A shouldn't even define a default constructor as long it seems to be useless without it's 'normal' constructor as the OPs question suggests.

Comment: @Chad This (what I stated in my comment) is a bit disguised in your code as `/* construct as appropriate */`. One should prevent constructing A any other ways.

Comment: @g-makulik why would that help?

Comment: I can see the argument that option 2 doesn't "require" `A` be constructed before `B` if code changes are made to initialize `B` in the initializer list.  However, it is a viable way to make it "work".  Given the vagueness of the questoin, I think option 1 is likely the best candidate.

Comment: @SethCarnegie You're right, it wouldn't really help about using uninitialized reference with `createB()`. Meanwhile I think it would be best either to eliminate `createB()` at all or follow Chad's 1st proposal.